# the kanji 細 which means details

Tags: kanji

I have a question that might be very trivial
I have encountered this kanji sai 細
I wish to know can I use it this way.
話の細 - the details of the story

Answer (score 6):

When a kanji has a particular meaning that does not mean that you can just use that kanji alone as that word. I have to question how much you investigated this to begin with, as any simple translation or dictionary lookup of "details" will get you several options. In this particular case you could say 話の詳細. Notice that 詳細 contains the kanji in question.

Comment: In general, I agree. However, do not overlook the word sai (細) . Here is a definition with a sample sentence: http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%B4%B0&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=1&index=07020000&pagenum=1

Comment: Good point. I guess he could have been referring to this but his wording made me think that he was referring specifically to using a lone kanji for its meaning rather than as the independent word.